# Make AVAudioPlayer play a music file through phone call (ear) speaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I want to play a music file through ear speaker,

What I am doing now is:

In **viewDidLoad** method ::::

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Initializing music file in **viewDidLoad** ::::

```
musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1985_Ring_" ofType:@"wav"]];                                                                        
click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
```

Now Playing file after routing audio in a method :::::

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None error:nil];
[click2 play];
```

It's playing through loud speaker. Please guide me the proper way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the category of `AVAudioSession` like this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

Find more details in [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW8):

> You can programmatically influence the audio output route. When using
>   the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category, audio normally goes
>   to the receiver (the small speaker you hold to your ear when on a
>   phone call).