# Play dialler tone on ear-speaker

Tags: ios, swift, voip, tokbox

I'm currently working on a VOIP based application. In which when a user calls another person I need to play a dialler tone on the ear-speaker. I've searched a lot, but couldn't find any solution yet. I've used the following code to play the dialler tone:

```
// This method plays the ringtone for incoming call
func playRingtone()
{
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ringing.mp3", ofType:nil)!
    let url  = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do
    {
        ringtonePlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        ringtonePlayer?.numberOfLoops = 5
        ringtonePlayer?.play()
    }
    catch let error
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

But it's playing on the loud speaker, not on the ear-speaker.

**Additional Info:** I'm using TokBox SDK

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make AVAudioPlayer play a music file through phone call (ear) speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476523/make-avaudioplayer-play-a-music-file-through-phone-call-ear-speaker)

Comment: There is no such facility provided by Tokbox library. You have to do that from your OS/framework.